# WHAT and IT clause in these sentences

Tags: clauses

1.New applicants are registered to the database and will soon be informed.

My answer:
**It is new applicants that are registered to the database and will soon be informed.**

2.Discovering the truth so early in the story was surprising.

My answer:
**1. It was surprising to discover the truth so early in the story.

2.What was surprising was discovering the truth so early in the story.**

Comment: Erm... yes, and?

Comment: Wanted to know if they are correct

Comment: This site does not offer proofreading services I am afraid. You will have to edit your answer to explain why you have doubts about a particular language issue.

Comment: @Hedge hog— I believe they are not correct. Something is amiss there. Perhaps lack of parallelism. _that are registered to the database_ and _**that** will soon be informed_ sounds okay to me.

Comment: The first sentence changes emphasis on simple clefting. The original answers the question "What happens to new applicants?" The simple cleft sentence answers the question "Who is it who are registered to the database and who will soon be informed?"  The nonsensically over-elaborate (except for emphasis) "It is fact that new applicants are registered to the database and will soon be informed" is a more accurate paraphrase.

Comment: If all you want to know is whether they are correct, the answer is yes, they are.